# How to find browser app settings using AngularJs or Other JavaScripts?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am trying to create a form which should work in the browsers on mobile devices (e.g. Safari on iOS, Chrome on Android, IE on Windows Mobile).

I’ve heard that starting from iOS8 it should be possible to upload from the image gallery on the phone/ipad or use the camera to take a photo, however the user needs to give permission for this and when he has refused this before (on a different site) it won’t work until he changes his settings.

Is there any way to detect that the user has disabled this setting.

Tried Several things with the help of below JavaScript plugins:

https://github.com/muaz-khan/DetectRTC

The below link shows how to detect OS, browser & device :

https://github.com/srfrnk/ng-device-detector/blob/master/ng-device-detector.js

But no luck :(. How can I detect the settings of browser/ native app, if user didn't allow to access the storage/file media ?

I don't want to use any framework, like Ionic or Cordova ?
Just want to implement in simple Javascript.

Comment: Please read [How do I ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).

Comment: @KhalidHussain Thanks for your suggestion. Any help on the scenario ?

Comment: Since you are using Angular already, [take a look at this one](https://angular-file-upload.appspot.com/)... It does have capture functionality for mobile.

Answer (score 1):

I tried using the input file to upload via iOS 9, and it worked fine without giving me the option to prevent this from happening again. I can't find a way to replicate your concern.

Why do you want to detect the settings? What is it you're trying to do? Provide a helpful message or something? I can't imagine it being possible to access a user's private settings just via JavaScript. That doesn't sound secure at all.

You can try testing if the file input is even supported, e.g.

[File Upload Support On Mobile](https://viljamis.com/2012/file-upload-support-on-mobile/)
 ([same code on Modernizr](https://github.com/Modernizr/Modernizr/blob/master/feature-detects/forms/fileinput.js))